# How to setup a development stage in my heroku pipeline

Tags: heroku

A default heroku pipeline has the stages `review-->staging-->production`
with `review` being optional.
There is a way to add a `development` stage - but I can't find how to do this anywhere.

Is there a way to do this through a config file in the repo, or CLI, or the web GUI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your question is answered [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/pipelines#i-don-t-see-a-development-stage-how-do-i-add-an-development-app).

Comment: This is not even an answer

Comment: The link attached to the answer says: 

"You can add the app to any other stage, and then using the context menu on the app card, move the app to “development”. Alternatively, you can go to the Deploy tab of the app and add it to a pipeline from there, while specifying the “development” stage."

I think this is good answer.

Answer (score 23):

Found it...

Create an app in the `staging` stage, after you create it, the menu on the app has the option `move to development`, and then the development stage is created/revealed.